# Add Row Numbers To an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How all how do you add rows numbers to an array using numpy?

I wish to print an array to look like the following:

```
               [1, 39, 41, 43],
               [2, 38, 32, 18],
               [3, 27, 14, 17],
               [4, 22, 21, 22],
               [5, 20, 28, 23]
```

With 1-5 being the row numbers

I can only print the array without row numbers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
np.insert(array, 0, np.arange(array.shape[0]), axis=1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.